# Vim highlighting bug

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm new to Vim and having problems with highlighting for TypeScript. It seems like at some point, the syntax highlighting just stops behaving correctly. As you can see in the picture, each "i" is a different color, the function braces are different colors, and comments are messed up as well. Usually the file is highlighted well up to a point, then after that, nothing is highlighted correctly. What could be the problem? I have a typescript LSP running, and my vimrc doesn't mess with highlighting but I can provide it if it's helpful. I'm running version 9.1.

```
// Expected comment color
function testFunction(): void {
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    // Why is this not seen as a comment?
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a single space between `i` and `<` it is "fixed".

[image]

I would just contact either author of typescript syntax or create an issue in vim repo.